# ubuntu 12.04 lts netbook installation throught usb

Tags: 12.04, usb, wubi, ubuntu-netbook

I want to install ubuntu 12.04 lts on my asus disney netbook and i can not launch wubi.exe from my usb drive when the computer starts up. I have checked BIOS settings and it is all ok because I have set it to start up from a removable disk. The problem is that I can not launch the program. I have tried to boot my usb drive but I am not sure if I have done it correctly. please help. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you cannot launce wubi.exe from bios, it is a Windows program.
Install it in Windows.
"Burn" your Ubuntu iso file to your usb stick, and from wubi install it (inside windows)
You end up with a windows boot, and can run Ubuntu in wubi, this is not a dualboot.